# python eval to target specific class variable at runtime

Tags: python, class, eval

I'm trying to bind a variable to a specific list within a class at runtime. The snippet below works, but I'd like to have the class name in the eval expression instead of the variable.  i.e. the equivalent of:

```py
mybin = 'bin2'
eval(foo.mybin)
```

which obviously won't work...  but I can't seem to figure out the syntax after various incarnations of trying to glue "foo' and "mybin' together.

```py
class A:
    bin1 = [3,6,9]
    bin2 = [12,14,25]

foo = A()

mybin = 'foo.bin2'

for bin in eval(mybin):
    print bin
```

outputs:

```
 12
 14
 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `eval`. For dynamic attribute access, python knows `getattr`:

```
mybin = 'bin2'
for bin in getattr(foo, mybin):
    print bin
```

Comment: Hazards of old / other language programming habits!  I'm new to python and had not run across getattr before.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `f-string` is what you might be fond of:

```
class A():
  bin1 = [1, 2]
  bin2 = [12, 14, 25]

foo = A()

my_bin = 'bin2'

print(eval(f'foo.{my_bin}'))
#[12, 14, 25]
```